# Flutter: Type <> is not a subtype of <>... but it is

Tags: inheritance, flutter, dart, casting

**Disclaimer:** I know that there are several somewhat similar questions, but none of them helped me understand what the problem in this specific case is.

---

I have created a utility widget that accepts a `ChangeNotifier` and automatically rebuilds the widget when the data changes.

The code for this widget is slightly shortened but what the question is about is visible:

```dart
class ChangeNotifierConsumer<T extends ChangeNotifier> extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChangeNotifierConsumer({
    Key key,
    @required this.notifier,
    @required this.builder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final T notifier;

  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, T cache) builder;

  @override
  _ChangeNotifierConsumerState createState() => _ChangeNotifierConsumerState();
}

class _ChangeNotifierConsumerState extends State<ChangeNotifierConsumer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.builder(context, widget.notifier);
}
```

```dart
class Model extends ChangeNotifier { ... }
```

I would then use the widget as follows, but that's where the error occurs:

```dart
ChangeNotifierConsumer<Model>(
    notifier: Model(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Model model) { ... }
)
```

---

**The exact error message is:**

`type '(BuildContext, Model) => ListView' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, ChangeNotifier) => Widget'`

There are also no compile time errors or output from dart analyze, only at runtime it failes.

Why does this error occur despite the model extending ChangeNotifier?

If I use the Builder as follows, then there is no problem:

```dart
    builder: (BuildContext context, dynamic model) { 
       Model model = model as Model;    
    }
```

Comment: Well, to begin with, your utility is built-in: `AnimatedBuilder`

Comment: I know about `AnimatedBuilder` but as i wrote "the widget is slightly shorted". I do additional stuff inside, which `AnimatedBuilder` does not. And besides that I got similar errors for other widgets but this one was the easiest to describe the problem with.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using in the builder function when you use it?

Comment: Can you post a minimal, complete, verifiable example?  I am unable reproduce your problem.  The error message is correct in that `(BuildContext, Model) => ListView` is *not* a subtype of `(BuildContext, ChangeNotifier) => Widget`, but it's not clear why it expects a `ChangeNotifier` argument.  Are you sure that you provided the exact code that you're encountering the error with?

Comment: I suspect that you have a name clash and this `Model` you are using is not the model class that you defined. Just ctrl+click(Intellij) on the `Model` in `ChangeNotifierConsumer<Model>(` and see where it takes you.

Comment: @DanielSzy I can't, because i pass it to different functions, so I would need to give you this code as well, which is not possible. But thats irrelevant what I do inside, the error occures in the builder line and does not change when i do not use the model at all.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus I know that this is not the case because first this is not the real name, I replaced it so that it is shorter for this example and second, I copied the upper code to a new project with no other files and I got the same error.

Comment: @jamesdin here is a full example: https://pastebin.com/WqF2wnRg. Why is `(BuildContext, Model) => ListView` not a subtype of `(BuildContext, ChangeNotifier) => Widget`. BuildContext is BuildContext, Model extends ChangeNotifier and ListView extends Widget. All of them are subtypes on their own or do I missunderstand something?

Comment: It is supposed be a subtype. This is a problem best solved with Intellij's type annotations (or whatever var to type action gotten with alt enter was called).

Answer (score 0):

Imho there is a small mistake in your approach of extending ChangeNotifier.

Extending something in OOP refers to a "is a".
For example, Lion extends Animal => Lion is a Animal.

In your case, by extending ChangeNotifier, you basically say:

Model is a ChangeNotifier , which is not the case. Correct me if I am wrong.

I tired to get my head around the type issue, but could not get a clue why that is.
Meanwhile, I worked on a example that would beT Type Save and work as you expect it.

**Full working example:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  TestModel _model = TestModel(
    'id', 'name'
  );

  _changeValue(){
    _model.setId('newId');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(56.0),
                child: ChangeNotifierConsumer<TestModel>(
                  model: _model,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(_model.id),
                        RaisedButton(
                          child: Text(_model.name),
                          onPressed: _changeValue,
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                )), Text(_model.id)
          ],
        )
      )
    );
  }
}


class ChangeNotifierConsumer<T extends Model> extends StatefulWidget {
  ChangeNotifierConsumer({
    Key key,
    @required this.model,
    @required this.builder,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final T model;
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context) builder;
  @override
  _ChangeNotifierConsumerState createState() => _ChangeNotifierConsumerState();
}

class _ChangeNotifierConsumerState extends State<ChangeNotifierConsumer> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.model.addListener(_listener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.model.removeListener(_listener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _listener() {
    print('setstate');
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => widget.builder(context);
}

abstract class Model with ChangeNotifier {

}

class TestModel extends Model {
  String _id;
  String _name;


  TestModel(this._id, this._name);

  get id => _id;
  get name => _name;

  setId(String id) {
    _id = id;
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```